# Existence of Indexing Functions with Certain Properties

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be any non-empty set, an indexing is a function $f:\mathcal{I} \rightarrow S$ such that $f$ is surjective. It is not hard to look for $f$ and $\mathcal{I}$ satisfying this definition (take the identity function). But let's say I want an indexing that allows for repetitions, that is, surjective $f:\mathcal{I} \rightarrow S$ such that for every $x\in S$ $|f^{-1}(\{x\})| \in \mathbb{N}$, how should I construct such an indexing? In my head, this seems doable, but I'm worried there are some set theoretic facts that I am overlooking.

Edit: I think I need the Axiom of Choice to actually construct this. Am I right?

Comment: Let I be an ordinal at least as big by cardinality, as S.

Comment: If you take e.g. $\mathcal I=S\times\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$ where $n\in\mathbb N$ then $f:\mathcal I\to S$ prescribed by $\langle s,i\rangle\mapsto s$ provides and indexing function with $|f^{-1}(\{s\})|=n$ for every $s\in S$. Is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes actually, I kind of figured out I can do it like that. Maybe I'll put my own answer. I guess it's not as complicated as I thought it would be.